# how to attach a camera to a moving object in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to do a review of a moving agent
Let’s think about the case of cars driving towards a parking floor and then returning to their starting point. In this case the agent would be of type “Car” and the instances of this agent could be multiple, which can be identified in the population “cars”. To place a camera that records any car within our car population, we simply go to the window of our agent type “Car” and set up a camera that can record our vehicle.

By default, our animation will be in the coordinates (0,0,0) in our “Car” window, so we can place the camera in (-60, 0, 15) so that it is 6 meters behind our car and 1.5 meters above the height at which the car is (calculated based on the distance scale).

Now we need to call that camera in our Main window, and for it, we can create a button or an event in the agent in which the car population lives (for instance Main), that fixes the view of the camera in our 3D Window. For it we must write the following code:

window3d.setCamera(cars.random().camera, true);

This way, our “window3d” will have as a view the “camera” of a random car of our created car population and will follow its trajectory since the option to follow the object is set to true.
I tried to attach the camera to the agent and create a button in main, but it doesn’t work.

Comment: "but it doesnt work" doesnt work. How should we help with that? Your basic approach is correct, so share details of the error and setup, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the camera into the agent.

Then, where ever your actual 3D window is, tell it to show that camera, for example `my3DWindow.setCamera(myAgent.myCamera)` (assuming your agent is embedded into the same agent as the 3D window, else [learn about how to navigate your model hierarchy](https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to))

Also check the `setCamera()` method, it has several options you can use to fine-tune how it works (use code-complete)